# Get specific part of dictionary instance

Tags: c#, linq

I need help to convert specific part of the dictionary instance, let's say for example I have this model instance

```
public class MyModel
{
  public int id {get;set;}
  public List<ClassC> classc {get; set;}
  public Dictionary<ClassA,ClassB> {get; set;}
}
```

on this MyModel instance, I need to remove ClassA and convert ClassB in dictionary instance to list and I will have this result. Is there a direct way to do this or I really need to extract each records and transfer each to new model class?

```
public class newMyModel
{
  public int id {get;set;}
  public List<ClassC> classc {get;set;}
  public List<ClassB> {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: You mean `.Keys` and `.Values`?

Comment: yes and the equivalent of that in my case is ClassA,ClassB

Answer (score 2):

You can define constructor of `newMyModel` that will accept as its parameter object of type `MyModel`:

```
public newMyModel(MyModel oldModel)
{
  this.id = oldModel.id;
  this.classc = oldModel.classc;
  this.classb = oldModel.dict.Values.ToList();
}
```

I assumed that `Dictionary` field in `MyModel` class is named `dict` and `List<ClassB>` in `newMyModel` is named `classb`.

Comment: dict.Values doesnt have ToList()

Comment: @MMb it's an extension method provided by LINQ. You need to add `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to use `Values.ToList()` which comes with linq.
Here is a complete sample for your case:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq; // <- Don't forget this

public class Program
{
    public class ClassA {
        public int A {get; set;}
    }
    public class ClassB {
        public int B {get; set;}
    }
    public class ClassC {
        public int C {get; set;}
    }

    public class MyModel
    {
        public int id {get;set;}
        public List<ClassC> classc {get; set;}
        public Dictionary<ClassA,ClassB> dic {get; set;}
    }

    public class NewMyModel
    {
        public int id {get;set;}
        public List<ClassC> classc {get;set;}
        public List<ClassB> listb {get; set;}
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        // Initializing MyModel
        MyModel a = new MyModel(){
            id = 1,
            classc = new List<ClassC>(){
                new ClassC(){
                    C = 1
                }
            },
            dic = new Dictionary<ClassA,ClassB>(){
                {
                    new ClassA(){
                        A = 1
                    },
                    new ClassB() {
                        B = 1
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        NewMyModel b = new NewMyModel() {
            id = a.id,
            classc = a.classc,
            // Converting values of the dictionary to list
            // Note: Values contains ClassB type of objects
            listb = a.dic.Values.ToList()
        };
    }
}
```

Note:
Don't forget to import `System.Linq` to make `ToList()` function available.